# Android studio missing classes (Constraint Layout) (has been resolved)

Tags: android

Android studio missing classes.
The layout is blank.
[image: BlackJack]

Main.Activity is red letters.

[image]

[Soultion in the answer area]

Comment: Have you migrated your project to AndroidX or use Support library?

Comment: Use Support library ?What is that ? I opened my project use this:File->Open->Black Jack->OK

Comment: Please move your solution into a new answer, and also please edit the question so that all material information is provided as inline text not via images. This will make the question easier for future enquirers to find and use. Thanks.

Comment: I have been changed my content.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution:

First,I delete Android Studio,and then Download Android Studio(include emulator and SDK) again.

Second,I change the name of my homework.

Third,I choose "Open an existing Android project".

Forth, Gradle Scripts->build.gradle->

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
}
```

replace

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
}
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
```

add this line under dependencies in your `build.gradle` file

Comment: after add this line you have to again sync your gradle file.

Comment: it writes "The project 'BlackJack' is not a Gradle-based project."

Answer (score 0):

If Android Studio is not identifying the project as Gradle based, it means you imported the project source code from wrong directory. Try to reimport the project from a directory where you have see build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps [Add ConstraintLayout to your project](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#add-constraintlayout-to-your-project)

Or if you are using AndroidX

You need to use different build artifacts

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
```

Refer here for AndroidX [Migrating to AndroidX](http://androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the problem

Comment: Please share solution, if it is resolved. It will help others.